# Rails devise custom urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, routes, devise

I'm aware that you can change the names of routes for devise, but I'm looking to actually add something to a devise route, like so:

```
match "users/sign_up/:invitation_token', :controller => 'registrations', :action => 'new'"
```

I've tried adding that line both directly above and directly below my devise routing declaration:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

But rails doesn't see the route.  Is there a way that I can add a parameter to the devise generated URL?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the goal? Devise routes are pretty closed to modification, except for things API allows, but maybe you can achieve solution to your task in some other elegant way.

Comment: The app I'm working on has a requirement of being invite-only, so I'm trying to find a way to integrate an invitation system that can pick up an invite token from the URL, as opposed to making a user cut and paste it (though that will still be an option).

Comment: What was the solution to this? I'm trying to the same exact thing. Following along with the railscast tutorial.

Comment: Looks like a typo? route should be(?) : `match "users/sign_up/:invitation_token", :controller => 'registrations', :action => 'new'`

Comment: that is not modifying the devise routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on rails 3 due to the use of the 'match' keyword. Try the following syntax

```
match 'users/sign_up/:invitation_token', :to => 'registrations#new'
```

Put this line below your `devise_for` line and you should be good to go.

And since your goals is to manage invitations, you'll probably want to check out https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable (haven't tried it myself)

Answer (score 2):

Still I was getting some routing error. This worked for me:

```
  devise_scope :user do 
    match "users/profile" => "sessions#show" 
  end
```